# Manually authenticate my user account with Google Calendar API v3

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

What I'm trying to do:

Allow users that are authenticated and authorized on my site to use a form that allows them to create events on my calendar using Google Calendar's API.

I was able to accomplish this through Google Calendar API v2 by manually authenticating my Google account by doing this:

```
calendar_service = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarService()
calendar_service.email = 'email@site.com'
calendar_service.password = 'password'
calendar_service.source = 'Calendar'
calendar_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
```

I could then pipe in the POST date from my site's form and create an event using the API, but I'm at a loss for how to do this with V3 of the API.

I have read the documentation and tried implementing:

```
created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

But this requires that a `service` object be created, which in turn requires account authentication through OAuth 2.0, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to manually authenticate *my own* calendar instead of asking a user if my application can access *their* calendar.

I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental logic or making some false assumptions. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use OAuth to authorize *your code* to access *your own calendar*; once you do that, you'll get a token that you can keep. When your code runs again, it should reuse the token to connect to *your* calendar. Users won't be challenged, but the token might be refreshed from time to time.

Can't suggest any code because I personally hate OAuth with a passion :(

Answer (score 0):

@Ben - The `service` object can be created either with a key/secret combination OR using a Service Account where you use a email/cert combination and the `prn` parameter to identify the user on which you want to operate.  Both methods require registration in your API console.

Using a Service Account, you could just specify your email address in the `prn` parameter to insert the event into *your* calendar.  The insert statement stays the same since you're operating on your account with this specification.

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', prn='you@domain.com')
...

created_event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

Here's an example of that:  https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation